# How do I query a tstzrange with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a [range of timestamp with timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) stored in one column of my PostgreSQL database, e.g:

```
timeRange (tstzrange)
["2019-02-10 23:00:00+00","2019-03-09 23:00:00+00")
```

**I want to query my database based on that column, testing if a given date range is contained by the range in my column.**

---

According to the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-range.html), I can query a range contained by another range with the `<@` operator:

```
 Operator | Description           | Example                          | Result
 <@       | range is contained by | int4range(2,4) <@ int4range(1,7) | t
```

According to the [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#range-operators), this can be done using the operator `$contained`:

```
$contained: [1, 2]     // <@ [1, 2) (PG range is contained by operator)
```

I have tried querying using this operator:

```
const start = '2019-02-11T00:30:00.000Z';
const end = '2019-02-08T02:30:00.000Z';
MyModel.findOne({
    where: {
        timeRange: {
            $contained:
                [
                    new Date(start),
                    new Date(end)
                ]
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't work and gets the error

```
error: operator does not exist: tstzrange = timestamp with time zone
```

The query looks like this

```sql
'SELECT * FROM "model" AS "model" WHERE  "model"."timeRange" = \'2019-06-26 22:00:00.000 +00:00\'::timestamptz;'
```

This probably explains why I got the PostgreSQL error. How can I properly format the query to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Using this similar question, I figured out a workaround but I'm not sure why or how it works : [Query with date range using Sequelize request with Postgres in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543566/query-with-date-range-using-sequelize-request-with-postgres-in-node)

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const start = '2019-02-11T00:30:00.000Z';
const end = '2019-02-08T02:30:00.000Z';
MyModel.findOne({
    where: {
        timeRange: {
            [Op.contained]: 
                [
                    new Date(start),
                    new Date(end)
                ]
        }
    }
});
```

If anyone has an explanation, I would be happy to hear it